# FoldList with Composition and parameter

Tags: iteration

Good day to everyone!

I have two (just for simple example) functions and they compose a map:

```
m[t_]:=RotationMatrix[t].#&
s[k_]:={#[[1]],#[[2]]-k2 #[[1]]^2}&
map=Composition[m[0.2],s[2]]
```

If I use this `map` in `NestList` all works nice:

```
NestList[map,{0.01,0.001},1000]
```

But now I want to change the first argument `t` of `m[t]` at each (or with some step) iteration. For this I was hoping to use `FoldList`, but this does not work:

```
FoldList[Composition[m[0.2+#2]&,s[2]],{0.01,0.001},Range[0.01,0.02,0.001]]
```

How can I use `Composition` in `FoldList`?

**EDIT**

I'm not sure can I add some more wishes or should I post another question.

To speed-up iterations, I can `Compile` functions:

```
mc=Compile[{t,{x,_Real,1}},{{Cos[t],-Sin[t]},{Sin[t],Cos[t]}}.x]
sc=Compile[{k2,{x,_Real,1}},{x[[1]],x[[2]]-k2 x[[1]]^2}]
```

Using `With` technique that @kglr advised in comment I can write:

```
FoldList[With[{xx = #2},RightComposition[mc[.2+xx,#]&,sc[2,#]&]],
{0.01,0.001},Range[0.01,0.02,0.001]]
```

This works. But what confuses me is that `#2` is in purple and `Composition` does not work when replaced `RightComposition`. What is the difference in this case between `Composition` and `RightComposition`? Am I using `Compile` correctly?

Comment: you probably meant `s[k2_]:=...`?

Comment: `FoldList[With[{xx = #2}, Composition[m[.2 + xx], s[2]]@#] &,...]`?

Comment: @kglr, yes, that works! You can post this as answer, and porbably add explanation of why direct using `#2` fails.

Comment: @kglr, I edited question, could you give me some hints, or answers?

Comment: "`s[k_]:={#[[1]],#[[2]]-k2 #[[1]]^2}&`" Is this a typo?

Comment: You've mixed `#`s up. Just rewrite the pure functions with named arguments: `FoldList[Composition[Function[{firstargument, secondargument}, m[0.2 + secondargument]], s[2]], {0.01, 0.001}, Range[0.01, 0.02, 0.001]]` Now can you see what's wrong?

Comment: Also, you haven't correctly understood @kglr 's comment. If I rewrite it as `FoldList[Function[{foldarg1, foldarg2}, With[{xx = foldarg2}, Composition[m[.2 + xx], s[2]]@foldarg1]], ...]`, is it easier to understand?

Comment: @xzczd, sorry I answer No to both your comments, I really don't understand. How can I use `mc, sc` from my question in `FoldList`?

Comment: A possible fix for the code using `m` and `s` is `FoldList[{foldarg1, foldarg2} |-> Composition[m[0.2 + foldarg2], s[2]]@foldarg1, {0.01, 0.001}, Range[0.01, 0.02, 0.001]]` (The notation `|->` is introduced in _v12.2_, if you're in earlier versions, use `\[Function]` instead. ) Persionally I prefer not to use `Composition`: `FoldList[{foldarg1, foldarg2} |-> m[0.2 + foldarg2]@s[2]@foldarg1, {0.01, 0.001}, Range[0.01, 0.02, 0.001]]` Now do you understand?

Comment: With my definitions from question: `mc = Compile[{t, {x, _Real, 1}}, {{Cos[t], -Sin[t]}, {Sin[t], Cos[t]}} . x], sc = Compile[{k2, {x, _Real, 1}}, {x[[1]], x[[2]] - k2 x[[1]]^2}]`, what is wrong with this: `FoldList[{foldarg1, foldarg2} |-> Composition[mc[0.2 + foldarg2, foldarg1], sc[2, foldarg1]], {0.01, 0.001}, Range[0.01, 0.02, 0.001]]`? I understand that for `Fold` I need a function of two arguments, can such `Composition` be used?

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder, for more info you may want to read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/284701 Notice `mc[0.2 + foldarg2, foldarg1]` won't evaluate to a function **relationship**. A possible fix: `FoldList[{foldarg1, foldarg2} |-> Composition[mcarg |-> mc[0.2 + foldarg2, mcarg], scarg |-> sc[2, scarg]]@foldarg1, {0.01, 0.001}, Range[0.01, 0.02, 0.001]]`

Comment: @xzczd, OK, "function relashionship" was the key to understand. Thank you so much!