# FoldList and Compile

Tags: compile, iteration

Let me elaborate my previous question [about Foldlist and Composition](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/244684/foldlist-with-composition-and-parameter).

```
mc[t_]:=Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},{{Cos[t],-Sin[t]},{Sin[t],Cos[t]}}.x, 
CompilationTarget->"C", RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True]
sc[k2_]:=Compile[{{x,_Real,1}},{x[[1]],x[[2]]-k2 x[[1]]^2}, 
CompilationTarget->"C", RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True]
```

I use `{Listable}` and `Parallelization` to speed-up iterations for many initial points. Now to `FoldList`. Using @kglr's suggestion from comments to previous question I can write:

```
FoldList[With[{xx = #2}, RightComposition[mc[0.2+xx], sc[2.]]]@#&,
{{0.01,0.001}, {-0.01,0.001}}, Range[0, 0.1, 0.001]]
```

Here I'm using just 2 inital points (there are much more in real application, also `RightComposition` is more complicated), this works, but VERY slow. I suppose it is because `Compilation` is done at every iteration step. And I have no idea how to fix this. Can someone help me to improve the code to make it work as fast as possible?

**ADD**

To address @MarcoB comment:

```
mc=Compile[{{x, _Real, 1},t},{{Cos[t],-Sin[t]},{Sin[t],Cos[t]}}.x, 
CompilationTarget->"C", RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True]
sc=Compile[{{x,_Real,1},k2},{x[[1]],x[[2]]-k2 x[[1]]^2},
CompilationTarget->"C", RuntimeAttributes->{Listable}, Parallelization->True]
```

And if I add one more `mc` to iteration, this gives errors:

```
FoldList[With[{xx = #2}, RightComposition[mc[#,0.2+xx]&, sc[#,2.]&, 
mc[#,0.3+xx]&]], {{0.01,0.001},{-0.01,0.001}}, Range[0,0.1,0.001]]
```

Errors I see:

Function::slotn: Slot number 2 in mc[#1,0.3 +#2]& cannot be filled from (mc[#1,0.3 +#2]&)[{{0.009602,0.00278236},{-0.00999934,-0.0012066}}].

CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument {{0.009602,0.00278236},{-0.00999934,-0.0012066}} at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument {{0.009602 Cos[0.3 +#2]-0.00278236 Sin[0.3 +#2],0.00278236 Cos[0.3 +#2]+0.009602 Sin[0.3 +#2]},{-0.00999934 Cos[0.3 +#2]+0.0012066 Sin[0.3 +#2],-0.0012066 Cos[0.3 +#2]-0.00999934 Sin[0.3 +#2]}} at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument {{0.979867 (0.009602 Cos[Plus[<<2>>]]-0.00278236 Sin[Plus[<<2>>]])-0.199649 (0.00278236 Cos[Plus[<<2>>]]+0.009602 Sin[Plus[<<2>>]]),0.199649 (0.009602 Cos[Plus[<<2>>]]-0.00278236 Sin[Plus[<<2>>]])+0.979867 (0.00278236 Cos[Plus[<<2>>]]+0.009602 Sin[Plus[<<2>>]])},{-0.199649 (-0.0012066 Cos[Plus[<<2>>]]-0.00999934 Sin[Plus[<<2>>]])+0.979867 (-0.00999934 Cos[Plus[<<2>>]]+<<22>> <<1>>),<<1>>+<<1>>}} at position 1 should be a rank 1 tensor of machine-size real numbers.

General::stop: Further output of CompiledFunction::cfta will be suppressed during this calculation.

Comment: Don't use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) in your definition of compiled functions. Use `Set` (`=`)  instead, ie `mc = Compile[....]`. You should also include $t$ as an argument to your compiled function.

Comment: @MarcoB, I changed `mc = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, t},...]` and `sc=Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, k2},...]`, then `FoldList[With[{xx = #2}, RightComposition[mc[#, 0.2 + xx] &, sc[#, 2.],  mc[#, 0.3 + xx] &]], {{0.01, 0.001}, {-0.01, 0.001}}, Range[0, 0.1, 0.001]]` gives errors.

Comment: Before "+1" to comment about `SetDelayed`, please read question -- using `Set` and placing `t` inside `Compile` does not help.

Comment: "gives errors" is unfortunately uninformative. Can you include the exact errors you get? Otherwise you limit potential helpers to only those that have time to run your code to see what errors you get.

Comment: @MarcoB, I added error messages. I naively thought that if there is minimal code, then  experienced users are able to run that and understand what is going on.

Comment: Great! No helpful answers, but "-1". Why? There is all needed information in question: one can run my code and see the errors. If you don't have solution or hint -- just ignore, for me it is adequate behavior. First time I see such a forum ...

Comment: `FoldList` is unrelated here. `With[{xx = #2}, 
  RightComposition[mc[#, 0.2 + xx] &, sc[#, 2.] &, mc[#, 0.3 + xx] &]][{{0.01, 
   0.001}, {-0.01, 0.001}}, 0]` is enough to reproduce the warning. As to why it doesn't work, if I rewrite the code as `((mc[#1, 0.2 + #2] &) /* (sc[#1, 2.] &) /* (mc[#1, 0.3 + #2] &))[{{0.01, 0.001}, {-0.01, 0.001}}, 0]`, is it easier for you to understand what's wrong?

Comment: You've made essentially the same mistake as in your [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/244684/1871). It's not a good idea to proceed before you've fully understood what's wrong with your original attempt.

Comment: @xzczd, I started this new question because there were no answers to my previous one, so I decided it is not clearly formulated and tried re-ask. I really don't understand and ask for help, but no one post elaborated answer, only comments and "-1" (I don't mean you).